# jQuery slideDown & show

Tags: jquery

I'm a beginner in coding jQuery. I would like to code a simple Slider. I can slide to the next image. But... how can I slide back? Maybe if/else?

Facts:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("#button").click(function() {
        $("#whiteLayer").slideDown("slow").delay(700).slideUp(400);
            $("#imageOne").delay(700).fadeOut();
            $("#imageTwo").delay(701).show();
});
})
```

I have also a example on codepen: http://codepen.io/huberloui/pen/WRKwjw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering your code snippets the sequence could look something like this:

1. Get the selector for the targeted image from `data-target`
2. Slide down the white layer
3. Hide all images (reset) but show the targeted image
4. Slide up the white layer again

So here's the updated snippet with logging and further comments in the code. Make sure to also check the HTML (you do not need the additional `#` for an ID).

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('#nav a').click(function() {
    var targetID = $(this).data('target'); // Select target image.
    $('#whiteLayer').slideDown('slow', function() {
      console.log('slideDown finished');
      $('#imageOne, #imageTwo').hide(); // Hide all images.
      $(targetID).show(); // Show targeted image.
      console.log('show ' + targetID);
    }).slideUp(400, function() {
      console.log('slideUp finished');
    });
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.headerimage {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#nav {
  margin-right: 100px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
#nav li {
  display: inline;
  float: right;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
#nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#whiteLayer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 5;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: none;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <div id="whiteLayer"></div>
  <img id="imageOne" class="headerimage" src="https://unsplash.it/600/200?image=29">
  <img id="imageTwo" class="headerimage" src="https://unsplash.it/600/200?image=30" />

  <ul id="nav">
    <li><a href="#" data-target="#imageOne">Test1</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#" data-target="#imageTwo">Test2</a>
    </li>
  </ul>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the attribute `data-toggle` to the tag `<a>` with the id of the `img`:

Ex:

`<li><a href="#" data-target="#imageOne">Test1</a></li>`

And on javascript/jQuery get the trigger element by event:
$(document).ready(function(event) {

```
$("#button").click(function() {
    var id = $(event.target).prop('data-target'); // event.target is the trigger element

    $("#whiteLayer").slideDown("slow").delay(700).slideUp(400);
        $(id).delay(700).fadeOut();
        $(id).delay(701).show();
```

});
})